# JavaFX: Can't show opacity transitions on transparent stages?

Tags: javafx, shadow, stage

What I'm trying to do is to show a fade-in/out transition effect on an transparent stage (pop-up notification) with shadow effect.

I created a transparent scene with a StackPane `fx:id="rootNode"` set to `-fx-background-color: transparent` and inside the StackPane I wrap an AnchorPane with a shadow effect. Next, I setup my transparent stage with that scene.

```
@FXML private StackPane rootNode;

Parent rootNode = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("notification.fxml"));
Scene scene = new Scene(rootNode, Color.TRANSPARENT);

Stage stage = new Stage();
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
stage.setScene(scene);
```

So far so good. I managed to get this transparent stage with a nice shadow effect.

**NOTE: The picture below shows my transparent stage with a shadow effect over my desktop, which has that cyan color.**

[image: transparent stage with shadow effect]

---

But now, since I've added some transition effects to gradually fade in and fade out the `Stage` (when user clicks on "x"), the `Stage` is barely shown. Something like the transition effect stops in the middle of its execution (I set to transform opacity from 0.0 to 1.0).

[image: barely shown]

You can see it in the taskbar below as there is a second java window which is that stage.

[image: taskbar]

---

If I place my cursor over the "x" button then it just shows up. Which means (I suppose) that transitions are played, but the stage is (somehow) not shown or transparent, until something graps its focus.

I tried

```
setting stage.toFront(); 
stage.requestFocus(); 
stage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

with no success.

When I change `StageStyle.UNDECORATED` on `Stage`, then the stage is shown with its transitions but there is that annoying white background around it, which is expected so.

[image: not transparent stage with shadow effect]

Could you please provide some help? I can't understand why this is happening or how to find a possible solution.

My setup is:

- Windows 7 x64 Pro
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b15)

---

--- UPDATE ---

After some testing, I conclude that there might be a "mis-compatibility" between **`StageStyle.TRANSPARENT`** stages and **transition opacity** effects ?

---

My transitions code is:

```
public class FadeTransition {

    private final Timeline showTransition, dismissTransition;
    private final NotificationStage stage;

    public FadeTransition(NotificationStage customStage) {
        this.stage = customStage;

        showTransition = setupShowTransition();
        dismissTransition = setupDismissTransition();
    }

    private Timeline setupShowTransition() {
        Timeline tl = new Timeline();

        // Set opacity to 0.0 instantly
        KeyValue kvOpacity = new KeyValue(stage.opacityProperty(), 0.0);
        KeyFrame frame1 = new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, kvOpacity);

        // Sets opacity to 1.0 gradually over 500 milliseconds.
        KeyValue kvOpacity2 = new KeyValue(stage.opacityProperty(), 1.0);
        KeyFrame frame2 = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), kvOpacity2);

        tl.getKeyFrames().addAll(frame1, frame2);

        //Action to be performed when the transition has finished
        tl.setOnFinished(e -> notificationIsShowing = true);

        return tl;
    }

    private Timeline setupDismissTransition() {
        Timeline tl = new Timeline();

        // At this stage the opacity is already at 1.0

        // Lower the opacity to 0.0 within 1000 milliseconds
        KeyValue kv1 = new KeyValue(stage.opacityProperty(), 0.0);
        KeyFrame kf1 = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000), kv1);

        tl.getKeyFrames().addAll(kf1);

        //Action to be performed when the transition has finished
        tl.setOnFinished(e -> {
            notificationIsShowing = false;
            stage.close();
            stage.setLocation(stage.getAnchorLocation());
        });

        return tl;
    }

    public void playShowTransition() {
        showTransition.play();
    }

    public void playDismissAnimation() {
        dismissTransition.play();
    }

    ... ... ...
}
```

Comment: Though I am not quite sure why this change in appearance in the newer versions, you can fix this by removing the `-fx-background-insets` and `-fx-border-insets` from the hbox's style.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha I changed the whole code. Please take a look. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: One question: is this a control from ControlsFX?

Comment: @PeterPenzov No, it isn't. This is my custom stage.

Comment: If this is a open source app can you share the code? I', interested how this solution is implemented.

Comment: The solution is not mine, but of the JavaFX devs team. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another guy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27038749/javafx-8-changing-the-opacity-of-the-stage-does-not-work-with-stagestyle-transpa) had the exact same issue and state it as a JavaFX bug.

The workaround is to build a custom `Interpolator` (bugFixInterpolator) to repaint the scene.

Here is a part of the code, posted in the above link:

```
Interpolator bugFixInterpolator = new Interpolator() {
            @Override
            protected double curve(double t) {
                Paint fill = scene.getFill();
                scene.setFill(Color.RED);
                scene.setFill(fill);
                return t;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "Interpolator.LINEAR";
            }
        };

        Timeline t = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(0),
                new KeyValue(stage.opacityProperty(), 1, bugFixInterpolator)),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), new KeyValue(stage
                        .opacityProperty(), 0, bugFixInterpolator)));
        t.setAutoReverse(true);
        t.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        t.playFromStart();
```